# How do I update the cache after a mutation in Apollo / GraphQL?

Tags: reactjs, caching, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

Firstly, thank you for your time reading this through.

I've tried to update the cache after a mutation based on a few methods.

At first, I was thinking of using context, but as I read through documents, I realized that this approach would be unnecessary with Apollo since the state is stored in the cache.

I've been exploring these documents:
[Making all other cache updates](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/#making-all-other-cache-updates); [update cache after a mutation](https://dev.to/lucis/update-apollo-cache-after-a-mutation-and-get-instant-benefits-on-your-ui-1c3b); [automatically update Apollo cache after mutation](https://dev.to/aerogear/automatically-update-apollo-cache-after-mutations-20n7); [updating client cache after mutation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58255167/react-apollo-updating-client-cache-after-mutation)

I'm leaning into the method mentioned in the first link since it's the official documentation.

Some questions I have:

1. Am I missing something fundamental?
2. Is it a simple bug? Like the wrong variable mentioned somewhere.
3. Do I need to query GET_LINKS somewhere?

Here is the code block for reference:

```
const [createLink] = useMutation(CREATE_LINK);
  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    createLink({
      variables: {
        slug: state.slug,
        description: state.description,
        link: state.link
      },
      update(cache, { data: { createLink } }) {
        console.log(cache);
        cache.modify({
          fields: {
            links(allLinks = []) {
              const newLinkRef = cache.writeFragment({
                data: createLink,
                fragment: gql`
                  fragment NewLink on Link {
                    id
                    slug
                    description
                    link
                    shortLink
                  }
                `
              });
              return [...allLinks, newLinkRef];
            }
          }
        });
      }
    });
    setState({
      slug: "",
      description: "",
      link: ""
    });
  }
```

Here is the full codebase for reference:
[codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-liskov-tkhtm?file=/src/components/CreateLink.js)

Comment: mutation always fails ('xxx already exists') then no `update` called ... mutation doesn't contain `id` then fragment doean't have all required data ... use readQuery, it's simpler ... https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-interaction/#combining-reads-and-writes

Comment: Hi xadm - Thanks for your thoughts. The mutation always failed due to a bug in my backend. The mutation should work now. But the update does not work. I removed the id from the fragment. Should the update work now? I'm reading into readQuery at the moment.

Comment: `allLinks(prevLinks = []) {` as `allLinks` is a 'field', a cache entry for query ... insert `debugger` and explore cache/data/ structures ... 'id' props are required for cache

Comment: Edited some variables. Added `id`. Can you elaborate more on fields? I'm currently receiving a `gql is not defined` error. It looks like the reference error could be a syntax error, but I'm not sure where the error is occurring.

Comment: `import { gql } from "@apollo/client";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you xadm for your thoughts. I ended up using `update`. I moved the update code block into the `useMutation` function out of the `handleSubmit` function.

Working code block:

```
const [createLink] = useMutation(CREATE_LINK, {
    update(cache, { data: { createLink } }) {
      debugger;
      cache.modify({
        fields: {
          allLinks(existingLinks = []) {
            const newLinkRef = cache.writeFragment({
              data: createLink,
              fragment: gql`
                fragment NewLink on Link {
                  id
                  slug
                  description
                  link
                }
              `
            });
            return [...existingLinks, newLinkRef];
          }
        }
      });
    }
  });
  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    createLink({
      variables: {
        slug: state.slug,
        description: state.description,
        link: state.link
      }
    });
    setState({
      slug: "",
      description: "",
      link: ""
    });
  }
```